# Обновление android studio 3.0

Tags: android-studio, update

Пытаюсь обновить android studio 3.0. Она у меня установлена по пути: D:\ProgramsD\Android\android-studio.

Я жму Help->Check for updates. Начинается загрузка обновлений, как сказано 5 Гб.
После этого у меня заканчивается память на диске C так как там свободно 22 Гб.
Забивается мусором папка C:\Windows\Temp.

Я сделал папку temp на диске D и сменил системные переменные
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но диск C по прежнему забивается!!!! Как объяснить android studio что диск С вобще трогать не нужно? Так как на диске D 500 Гб свободно. Никаких настроек по этому поводу я не нашел.

Как исправить всю эту лажу?

Comment: А разве 3.0 уже stable??

Comment: Я только начал работать со студией. За обновлениями не слежу

Answer (score 0):

Советую в этом случае перестановить официальную версию android studio уже версии 4.1. C [официального сайта](https://developer.android.com/studio)